# gspread_pandas - how to automate daily task and add new row at the row 2 or end of sheet

Tags: python, pandas, gspread

I have a script that I run manually. Every day I am changing start='A2' to A+1,. Finally I have some time to automate it with Google Cloud, but I don't know how to insert new row above A2 after script is successful (so i can make a space for script data and not to override previous day) or find last not empty row and add new row and insert data to it.

My dataframe and code:

```
day_summary = {'Dzień': yesterday,
                'Przychód brutto': total_value.round(2),
                'Przychód netto': total_value_vat.round(2),
                'Koszt': total_cost.round(2) + koszt_wysylka,
                'Koszt Facebook Ads': cost_fb,
                'Zysk (produkty)': zysk.round(2),
                'Koszty stałe': koszty_stale
                }
  df_day_summary = pd.DataFrame(day_summary, index=[1], columns=['Dzień', 'Przychód brutto', 'Przychód netto',
                                                                    'Koszt', 'Koszt Facebook Ads', 'Zysk (produkty)', 'Koszty stałe'])

  #wrzuć całe info do docsa
  spread = gspread_pandas.Spread("[spreadshetname", config=c)
  spread.df_to_sheet(df_day_summary, index=False, sheet='nowa_rentownosc', start='A2', replace=False, headers= False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I used:
pozycja = spread.get_sheet_dims(sheet="nowa_rentownosc")
pozycja = pozycja[0]+1

and it worked. :)